# How do you report significant contrast results for a MANOVA in APA style?

Tags: manova, contrasts

Do you just report that MANOVA significance test is significant, or do you have to include contrast estimates (SPSS `K MATRIX`)? In the latter case, what are recommended formatting guidelines?

Answer (score 3):

The APA doesn't provide free access to their style guide. However, I found [this reference](http://www.chajewski.com/Teaching/Graduate/hmw6_answer_key.pdf) illustrating the write-up of a MANOVA. If you wish to use tables to report your contrasts, [this 2010 document](http://osil.psy.ua.edu/~Rosanna/PY602/Writing%20up%20your%20results%20%E2%80%93%20APA%20Style%20guidelines.pdf) illustrates the general APA format for tables.

Another thought: the APA does a print publication of its style book. If you're at a university or have access to one, the library often has these types of books in their references section, although some require you to have a university ID to access those books. The Psychology department/faculty may also have a copy.

Best wishes with your write-up. :)

Answer (score 1):

The APA publication manual provides general guidelines on statistical copy but does not discuss MANOVA specifically. The APA also publishes a book called “Presenting your findings” (full reference below) that does include a MANOVA example. The choice of elements to report should depend on the publication (journal article vs. thesis) and the specific hypotheses discussed in the text. The most comprehensive reporting style (dubbed “play it safe” table in the book, presumably relevant for theses, not for journal articles anymore) includes

- a table of means and standard deviations for the dependent variables
- a table of correlations among the dependent variables
- multivariate and univariate ANOVA summary tables

That said, in practice you will often see that much less if reported, often only the test the authors want to interpret so you might get away with that, even in APA journals.

I did not find any discussion of contrasts in the book.

Nicol, A. A. M., & Pexman, P. M. (2010). *Presenting your findings: A practical guide for creating tables (6th ed.).* Washington, DC : American Psychological Association.